# Is it possible to solve problems about finding the number of solutions to a linear equation with the multinomial coefficient?

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

I have an exercise in combinatorics:

> There are $6$ **w**hite balls, $8$ **r**ed balls, $4$ **y**ellow balls and $6$ **b**lack balls. In how many ways can I pull $6$ balls?

Is it possible to solve it with the multinomial coefficient? I just started reading about them in Harris/Hirst/Mossinghoff's *Combinatorics and Graph Theory* and I sense it's possible, It appears that it would be possible, but I sense that it would be a little overkill.

It seems that if I take: $\displaystyle{6 \choose w,r,y,b}$, then I'd have to assign combinations for $w,e,y,b$, like taking first: $\displaystyle{6 \choose 6,0,0,0}$ and then $\displaystyle{6 \choose 5,1,0,0}$ and then $\displaystyle{6 \choose 5,0,1,0}$ and continuing through this process (this is what I meant with overkill). The book seems to tell me that there is a simpler way, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are the white (red, yellow, black) balls distinguishable? The analysis is very different if they are than if they are not.

Comment: **Hint:** You have $6+8+4+6=24$ balls in total. Now, in how many way can you pull $6$ balls out of a total of $24$ ? Well, in $\displaystyle{24\choose6}$ ways, of course. But there are obviously many repetitions amongst these $\displaystyle{24\choose6}=134596$ ways. So the problem becomes finding out just how many exactly, and then divide $134596$ by that number.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Not distinguishable.

Comment: @Lucian No, I'm not asking how to solve it. I'm asking if it's possible to solve it using multinomial coefficients.